# How to solve this definite integral from fourier series?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck with this integral:

$$\int\limits_0^{2L} \sin \left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) \sin \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)\, dx.$$

How to solve this integral? In general, can you refer me to formulas to solve this types of integral? Thanks.

Comment: Another possible way is to use $$\sin \alpha x=\frac{e^{i\alpha x}-e^{-i\alpha x}}{2i}$$.  It is algebraically tedious, but will always work and you just have to integrate exponentials.

Comment: See [trigonometric identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sin \left(\frac{m \pi x}{L}\right) \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right)
= \frac 12 \left[\cos \left(\frac{(m+n) \pi x}{L}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{(m-n) \pi x}{L}\right)\right]
$$